# Why I am not authorized with Docker? you are not authorized to perform this operation: server returned 401

Tags: docker

I build my image and try to run it

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name mern-stack mern-image:1.1
docker: you are not authorized to perform this operation: server returned 401.
```

I tried to add docker trust

```
docker trust signer add --key miki.pub miki mern-image:1.1
Adding signer "miki" to mern-image:1.1...
you are not authorized to perform this operation: server returned 401.

failed to add signer to: mern-image:1.1
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.
This is inside my .docker folder
~/.docker$ ll

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   4 miki miki  4096 Mar 14 11:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 174 miki miki 12288 Apr  3 11:10 ../
drwx------   5 miki miki  4096 Mar 14 11:18 buildx/
-rw-------   1 miki miki    99 Jul 15  2022 config.json
-rw-------   1 miki miki    74 Apr  3 10:45 .token_seed
-rw-------   1 miki miki     0 Mar 14 11:18 .token_seed.lock
drwx------   4 miki miki  4096 Dec  7 13:42 trust/
```

Just to check hello-world

```
docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

Users in docker group

```
grep /etc/group -e "docker"
docker:x:998:miki,gitlab-runner
```

I am providing inspect of my image,hosntame is empty!!!!
docker inspect identidock:latest

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:9e20dd253a91c43510e661a3c08c8dd47f96b7b8ad69cf59089311f9ad13b31a",
        "RepoTags": [
            "identidock:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
        "Created": "2023-04-03T14:29:25.956605761+02:00",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
```

Docker version empty!!

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS       PORTS                                                                                    NAMES
62c3bb684f1a   registry        "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   20 hours ago   Up 5 hours   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp                                                registry
1e1a42f2eaf5   notary_server   "/usr/bin/env sh -c …"   23 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:4443->4443/tcp, :::4443->4443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->8080/tcp, :::32768->8080/tcp   notary_server_1
69b9d8e29158   notary_signer   "/usr/bin/env sh -c …"   23 hours ago   Up 4 hours                                                                                            notary_signer_1
ed99861b486c   mariadb:10.4    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 hours ago   Up 4 hours   3306/tcp                                                                                 notary_mysql_1
```

I added both Notary sever and signer,these containers are running.

```
docker -D run -d --name mern-stack mern-image:2.0
DEBU[0000] reading certificate directory: /home/miki/.docker/tls/notary.docker.io 
DEBU[0000] No yubikey found, using alternative key storage: no library found 
DEBU[0000] Making dir path: /home/miki/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/mern-image/changelist 
DEBU[0001] received HTTP status 401 when requesting root.
```

Why?
How to find out what is wrong with my permissions?

Comment: better is to verify using docker  Hello-World `docker run hello-world` & if this doesn't work then it means docker-installation has some permission-issue. then you can focus only on docker configuration and not on docker-image or container.

Comment: @fly2matrix helloworld works fine,the problem is with every image I bake myself.

Comment: then - I believe it could be local policies that is causing this issue. try removing port binding `-p 80:80` while creating container from your command.

Comment: @fly2matrix Wrong,I will edit now.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to run 'docker login' to login to the registry first.

Comment: docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/miki/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded

Comment: The same again.